# How to get All Column names of table in magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, blocks

I created a custom form in admin using block(without UI component). So i want to get all columns of my custom table in form block file. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this add New function in your custom **resource model** and call that function where you want to display.

`public function getFields()
{
    $fields = $this->getConnection()->describeTable($this->getMainTable());
    return $fields;
}`