# How to get column name cms_page table in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, database

I am trying to create a field in system config to display a list of column names of the cms_page table. How to achieve this. please help me[image]

Comment: Please check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/245472/84221. You can return columns data from source model for this field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Try This**

**app/code/VendoreName/BasicModule/etc/adminhtml/system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="vendorename" translate="label" sortOrder="201">
            <label>VendoreName</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="basicmodule" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Basic Module</label>
            <tab>vendorename</tab>
            <resource>VendoreName_BasicModule::basicmodule_config</resource>
            <group id="genaral_setting"
                   translate="label"
                   type="text"
                   sortOrder="10"
                   showInDefault="1"
                   showInWebsite="1"
                   showInStore="1">
                <label>General Settings</label>
                <field id="admin_list"
                       translate="label"
                       type="select"
                       sortOrder="10"
                       showInDefault="1"
                       showInWebsite="1"
                       showInStore="1">
                    <label>CMS Page Fields</label>
                    <source_model>VendoreName\BasicModule\Model\Adminhtml\System\Config\Source\CMSPageData</source_model>
                    <comment><![CDATA[Comment are <b>write here</b>.]]></comment>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/BasicModule/Model/Adminhtml/System/Config/Source/CMSPageData.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\BasicModule\Model\Adminhtml\System\Config\Source;

class CMSPageData implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{

    public function getOptionArray()
    {
        $options = [];

        $options['page_id'] = __('Entity ID');
        $options['title'] = __('Page Title');
        $options['page_layout'] = __('Page Layout');
        $options['meta_keywords'] = __('Page Meta Keywords');
        $options['meta_description'] = __(' Page Meta Description');
        $options['meta_title'] = __('Page Meta Title');
        $options['identifier'] = __('Page String Identifier');
        $options['content_heading'] = __('Page Content Heading');
        $options['content'] = __('Page Content');
        $options['creation_time'] = __('Page Creation Time');
        $options['update_time'] = __('Page Modification Time');
        $options['is_active'] = __('Is Page Active');
        $options['sort_order'] = __('Page Sort Order');
        $options['layout_update_xml'] = __('Page Layout Update Content');
        $options['custom_theme'] = __('Page Custom Theme');
        $options['custom_root_template'] = __('Page Custom Template');
        $options['custom_layout_update_xml'] = __('Page Custom Layout Update Content');
        $options['layout_update_selected'] = __('Page Custom Layout File');
        $options['custom_theme_from'] = __('Page Custom Theme Active From Date');
        $options['custom_theme_to'] = __('Page Custom Theme Active To Date');

        return $options;
    }

    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $res = $this->getOptions();
        array_unshift($res, ['value' => '', 'label' => '']);
        return $res;
    }

    public function getOptions()
    {
        $res = [];
        foreach ($this->getOptionArray() as $index => $value) {
            $res[] = ['value' => $index, 'label' => $value];
        }
        return $res;
    }

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return $this->getOptions();
    }
}
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: It works fine. Thank a lot!